# How to store data in database(sqlite)

Tags: ios, sqlite

On iOS, I want store user data in database using sqlite. For that design .Xib file username, password, DOB as text fields and take button, after fill all text fields when click the button all the data is stored in database.

Comment: Is Core Data also acceptable? You can set it up to use SQLite.

Comment: Add more tag will help u more fast.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you already know how outlets work and how to get information from UI elements.

SQLite part. SQLite is very easy. You need to have an INSERT query, like this:

```
char *query = "INSERT INTO myTable (field1, field2) VALUES (?, ?)";
sqlite3_stmt *statem;
sqlite3_prepare_v2(myDB, query, -1, &statem, NULL);
sqlite3_bind_text(statem, 1, [[field1 text] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
sqlite3_bind_text(statem, 2, [[field1 test] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
do {
  int status = sqlite3_step(statem);
} whlie (status != SQLITE_DONE && status != SQLITE_ERROR);
```

You should set up the DB first but this can all be found in the documentation.