# How do I save text from a UITextField into an SQLite Database?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sqlite

I have seen many tutorials how to read data from an SQLite db, but never to write to one. 
I want to save a UITextField 's text into a field in a database table.
How would you do this? is it possible? please include any links that would help.

thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to store data in database(sqlite)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469003/how-to-store-data-in-databasesqlite)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GetDatabasePath method get the database path.

```
- (void)insertIntoDtabase:(NSString*)text  {


    sqlite3_stmt *statement = nil;
    char sql[1000];
    sprintf(sql, "Insert into *yourtablename* values ('%s')",[text UTF8String], );

    NSString *path = [self GetDatabasePath] ;
    if(sqlite3_open([path UTF8String],&database) == SQLITE_OK )
    {
        if((sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL)) == SQLITE_OK)
        {   
            //NSLog(@"%s",sql);
            sqlite3_step(statement);
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);


}
```

you call call this method when you want to add the text field data in your database and pass the textfield data as parameter.

Comment: where do you I the code? appDelegate, ViewController, Another class...?


This line:

sprintf(sql, "Insert into *yourtablename* values ('%s')",[text UTF8String], );  


gives an error: expected expression before ')' token.


Another error is " 'database' undeclared". Am i supposed to fill in this value? thanks.

Comment: I assumed that you have created and inilized the database and line will give  error because you have to write your table name.

Comment: i inserted my table name. i have created my database and put it in the resources folder and imported the class <sqlite3.h> and used the libsqlite3.dylib framework. anything more i need to do?

Comment: yes you have to inilize your database also http://www.iphonesdkarticles.com/2008/10/sqlite-tutorial-selecting-data.html this link will help you  in understanding sqlite

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to access an SQLite database on iOS, you can as well learn how to do it using [Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html).

> One of the simplest metrics is that,
>   with Core Data, the amount of code you
>   write to support the model layer of
>   your application is typically 50% to
>   70% smaller as measured by lines of
>   code. This is primarily due to the
>   features listed above—the features
>   Core Data provides are features you
>   don’t have to implement yourself.

But unless you have a good amount of data to store, it would be faster and easier to use `NSUserDefaults` instead SQLite. Example:

```
NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:myString forKey:@"KEY"];
NSString *string = [defaults objectForKey:@"KEY"];
```